# Merge items of two arrays into one array to the other in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an stdClass Object array below, but I want to merge the items into a single array as show below;

Current Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [photoid] => pht11a138355.jpg
            [propertyid] => PTY698082F7A
            [phototitle] => N/A
            [photodescription] => N/A
            [coverphoto] => 1
            [photovisible] => 1
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [photoid] => phtd9d04dc92.jpg
            [propertyid] => PTY7419F7A38
            [phototitle] => N/A
            [photodescription] => N/A
            [coverphoto] => 1
            [photovisible] => 1
        )

)
```

What I would like to achieve;

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [photoid] => pht11a138355.jpg
            [propertyid] => PTY698082F7A
            [phototitle] => N/A
            [photodescription] => N/A
            [coverphoto] => 1
            [photovisible] => 1
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [photoid] => phtd9d04dc92.jpg
            [propertyid] => PTY7419F7A38
            [phototitle] => N/A
            [photodescription] => N/A
            [coverphoto] => 1
            [photovisible] => 1
        )
)
```

Is it possible to do it in PHP

This is part of the script that I am using;

```
foreach ($data['searchresults'] as &$row) {

$photo_array = $this->Properties_model->getimg($row->propertyid);

$photodata = $this->Properties_model->getimg($row->propertyid);

$data['photos'] = arrayToObject($photo_array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($photo_array);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array(array(
            "photoid" => "pht11a138355.jpg",
            "propertyid" => "PTY698082F7A",
            "phototitle" => "N/A",
            "photodescription" => "N/A",
            "coverphoto" => 1,
            "photovisible" => 1
            )
);

$arr2 = Array(array(
            "photoid" => "phtd9d04dc92.jpg",
            "propertyid" => "PTY7419F7A38",
            "phototitle" => "N/A",
            "photodescription" => "N/A",
            "coverphoto" => 1,
            "photovisible" => 1
        )
);

$array  = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `array_merge`.

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for array_merge.

The documentation is here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes..Use `array_merge($array1,$array2)`

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge` is already available

```
<?php
$beginning = 'foo';
$end = array(1 => 'bar');
$result = array_merge((array)$beginning, (array)$end);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Taken from php documentation. You should have seen there first.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it out!